# what does !~myVar do?

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to read this code:

```
  var cloneKeys = Object.keys(base).filter(function ( k ) {
    return !~noCloneKeys.indexOf(k);
  });
```

What does the `!~` do here? I've never seen it before, and it's difficult to search. From the [expressions and operators reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) it looks like a combination of a logical operator and a bitwise operator, but that doesn't really make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is a (very unreadable) short form of `noCloneKeys.indexOf(k) == -1`.

```
~value = binary inverse, ~(-1) => 0
!value = boolean inverse, !(0) => true
```

To keep your fellow developers mentally sane, please write `== -1` or `< 0`...

---

Detailed:

```
-1 == binary 11111111111111111111111111111111 (assuming 32 bit integer)
~(-1)   ==   00000000000000000000000000000000
!(~(-1)) == !(0) == true
```

Comment: I think it's actually checking to see if `k` is *not* in the `noCloneKeys` set. The `~foo.indexOf(bar)` trick allows `.indexOf()` to be used as if it returned a boolean result, so prefixing it with `!` makes it mean "not in the list" (or the string, whatever that is).

Comment: true, thank you, edited my answer. See, kids? that's what happens to developers if you let them read `!~(-1)` too often - they go mental!

Answer (score 1):

This is the combination of two operators not `!` and tilde `~`.

Tilde (bitwise Not) - `~`:

This operator performs `-(input + 1)` (it actually is flipping bits, but I think that this is a nice beginner way to think about it). So in the case of `indexOf()`, which returns `-1` if the input is not found, tilde will convert `-1` to `0`. For all cases where the input is found, tilde will convert a `0` or greater value to `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, `-4`, etc.

Not - `!`:

This is a boolean operator that inverts the input. Or in your case will invert any `0` to true, and any non zero to `false`.

So if we combine them, we are saying give me `0` for any instance where `indexOf` cannot find the input, and invert it to `true`. For all other valid inputs return `false`.